# Is there an API similar to Google Earth API which allows me to see 3d Earth and navigate through it?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I want to build a mobile application which should have a screen with a `3D Earth` which is **spinning** and allows user to enter a **search query** to see a city from above.

I would like to have a `3D earth` similar to the picture above, where users can rotate the globe, zoom in/out etc.

[image]

I don't think creating my own model would help. (using openGL or something like this).

What is really important is that I would like to have the `same functionality of Google Earth/Maps` (like search, pins, routes etc)

Also I would like to color a whole country with a specific color like in th example but filled).

Is there an **API** that I could use? I didn't find anything relevant on Google yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Try map box](https://www.mapbox.com/maps/)

Mapbox is built on vector maps, an advanced approach to mapping where data is delivered to the device and precisely rendered in real-time. The result is smooth, fast maps.

They also provide studio to create custom maps.